# Discrete Spectrum

Tags: functional-analysis

Suppose $T: H\rightarrow H$ is a self-adjoint bounded linear operator that is not compact and $H$ is infinite dimensional real separable Hilbert space. Can $T$ have a discrete spectrum?

Comment: The identity operator, or (if you want more points in the spectrum) direct sum of various multiples of identity.

Comment: Thanks you Pavel, I feel like a dumb with your example, haha.

Comment: If T is not compact, then the spectrum will be discrete. If you define T in a compact region, then it is not discrete. If you define T in a non-compact region, then it is discrete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any compact set in can be a spectrum of some operator.

If an operator is self-adjoint then its spectrum lies on the real line

A normal operator is compact if and only if its spectrum is discrete, the only possible limit point of the spectrum is $0$ and the eigenspace for each non-zero eigenvalue is finite-dimensional. (credit goes to user53153 for pointing an error in the original answer).

These facts are enough to produce a lot of desired operators.

Comment: How can I prove this afirmation: If spectrum is discrete and the only possible limit point of the spectrum is 0 then the operator is compact.

Comment: @Tomás I guess Norbert was posting quickly. The spectrum of identity is $\{1\}$ but it it not a compact operator. We should assume that the operator is normal, so that the spectral theorem applies. Also, that the eigenspace for each non-zero eigenvalue is finite-dimensional. Then the compactness follows like this: for any given $\epsilon>0$, you can remove finitely many dimensions (i.e., subtract a finite-rank operator) so that the remainder has norm less than $\epsilon$. (Recall that an operator is compact iff it is the norm limit of finite-rank operators.)